# Slow responding scrollbar while using DefaultTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, simpledateformat, tablecellrenderer

I'm working on a desktop app which requires comparing dates between arrivals and departures of train times and highlight differences in various colour codes. I'm currently facing 2 problems:-

1. Although the code listed below works fine as long as the functionality is concerned, the responsiveness of the scrollbar is very slow, while importing a large file with many rows.
2. The date format is of the form "dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss", but there might be a situation while reading the date values from the file as some of the dates may have null values that may be represented by " " or simply "-". Is there a way to convert null values to the above defined Simple Date format?

Would really appreciate if anyone could help with this. Cheers!!!

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;

    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;


    public class CellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{


    public CellRenderer(){
        super.setOpaque(true);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object obj, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, obj, 
                isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        /*Define Date format*/

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss");  

        /*Date Array Initialisation*/

        Date [][] actDep = new Date[row+1][1];
        Date [][] planDep = new Date[row+1][1];
        Date [][] actArr = new Date[row+1][1];
        Date [][] planArr = new Date[row+1][1];

        String values=(String) table.getValueAt(row, column);

        String actArr1 = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 6);
        String planArr1 = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 3);
        String actDep1 = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 7);
        String planDep1 = (String) table.getValueAt(row, 4);


        long [][] arrDiff = new long[row+1][1];
        long [][] depDiff = new long[row+1][1];

        /*Parse Date Arrays*/

        for (int i = 0; i<=row; i++) {
            if(values.equals("-"))
            {
                table.setValueAt("01-JAN-01 00.00.00", row, column);
            }
            try {
                actDep[i][0] = format.parse(actDep1);
                planDep[i][0] = format.parse(planDep1);
                actArr[i][0] = format.parse(actArr1);
                planArr[i][0] = format.parse(planArr1);  

                /*Calculate differences in actual and planned arrivals in milliseconds*/    
                arrDiff[i][0]=actArr[i][0].getTime() - planArr[i][0].getTime();

                /*Calculate differences in actual and planned departures in milliseconds*/  
                depDiff[i][0]=actDep[i][0].getTime() - planDep[i][0].getTime();
        }
            catch(ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        Color lightOrange = new Color(255,215,0);
        Color darkOrange = new Color(255,140,0);
        Color aqua = new Color(0,255,255);
        Color pinky = new Color(255,0,255);


        /**
         * Colours have been highlighed in the table based on the following:
         * Aqua - early arrivals and departures
         * Green - no delay, departures within a minute
         * Yellow - up to five minutes late
         * Light Orange - 5-7 minutes late
         * Dark Orange - 7-10 minutes late
         * Red - later than 10 minutes
         * Pink - unplanned arrivals and departures
         * Gray - missed events
         */

        for(int i=0; i<=row; i++){

        if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0] >= 600000 && arrDiff[i][0] < 21600000) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0] >= 600000 && depDiff[i][0] < 21600000)))
            cell.setBackground(Color.RED);      

        else if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0] >= 420000 && arrDiff[i][0] < 600000) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0] >= 420000 && depDiff[i][0] < 600000)))
            cell.setBackground(darkOrange);

        else if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0] >= 300000 && arrDiff[i][0] < 420000) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0] >= 300000 && depDiff[i][0] < 420000)))
            cell.setBackground(lightOrange);

        else if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0] >= 60000 && arrDiff[i][0] < 300000) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0] >= 60000 && depDiff[i][0] < 300000)))
            cell.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        else if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0]== 0 && arrDiff[i][0] < 60000 && !actArr1.equals("01-JAN-01 00.00.00")) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0]== 0 && depDiff[i][0] < 60000 && !actDep1.equals("01-JAN-01 00.00.00"))))
            cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        else if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0]>= -600000 && arrDiff[i][0] < 0) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0]>= -600000 && depDiff[i][0] < 0)))
            cell.setBackground(aqua);

        else if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0] > -600000 && !actArr1.equals("01-JAN-01 00.00.00")) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0] > -600000 && !actDep1.equals("01-JAN-01 00.00.00"))))
            cell.setBackground(pinky);

        else if((column == 6) && (arrDiff[i][0] < -600000) || ((column == 7) && (depDiff[i][0] < -600000)))
            cell.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        else{

            cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            cell.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
      }
      }

       return cell;

}

}
```

Comment: What do you want the null values to be parsed to?

Comment: Would want to treat null values as "01-JAN-01 00.00.00".

Comment: So you can use a try-catch-block, in try parse date, and in catch set date to 01-jan-01 00.00.00

Comment: Alright then, managed to deal with the 2nd problem dealing with null values using if else conditions, e.g.- if (date == "-"){
         format.parse("01-JAN-01 00.00.00");
       } That was easier than I thought.                                                           Still stuck with the 1st problem though,i.e. responsiveness of the scrollbar is very slow, while importing a large file with many rows.Help please...

Comment: Then try double-buffering , its not easy but it would be a solution for the 1st problem

Comment: But JTable uses double-buffering by default right? I read it in one of the posts. Could you please elaborate on how to use it in my particular program so that I can give it a try.

Comment: Oracle states that swing has a mechanism to support double buffering and that it is turned on by default … but if it would be on you won't have the scroll bar that slow down.